# Почему не могу получить доступ к методам dll библиотеки?

Tags: java, c, com, jni

Добрый день, работаю с JNA подключился через интерфейс к .dll библиотеке но при вызове из неё метода пишет

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'сonnect': Не найдена указанная процедура.

но она там есть 
вот запись в самой библиотеке

```
function Connect(ChannelName: BSTR; Flags: I4; Username: BSTR; Password: BSTR): I4; stdcall;
```

Вот мой рабочий код

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

ClientW ClientW = (ClientW) Native.loadLibrary("spn", ClientW.class);

  System.out.println("connect = " +ClientW.Сonnect(nuberChanell,SPR_CHANNEL_HARDNAME,null,null));
}




public interface ClientW extends Library {

int Connect(int flags,
            java.lang.String username,
            java.lang.String password);
      }
```

Что ему не нравится?

Comment: С заглавной буквы: **C**onnect ?

Comment: @PavelParshin пробовал тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это означает, что Java не может загрузить библиотеку. Это может быть из-за того, что:

- Библиотека отсутствует в путях поиска
- Библиотека неправильно названа
- У вас не хватает прав для доступа к этой библиотеке
- Библиотека 32х битная на 64х битной системе
- JRE не настроен
- Библиотека требует другую, которой у вас нет
- DLL не собран как JNI или используется как JNA

Comment: Библиотека отсутствует в путях поиска по как её не положил в корень то выдавало вот это Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'spn': Native library (win32-x86/spn.dll) not found in resource path после этого то чтоуже писал

Comment: Библиотека неправильно названа вы имеете ввиду это название "spn" ?

Comment: У вас не хватает прав для доступа к этой библиотеке работаю под админом

Comment: Библиотека 32х битная на 64х битной системе нет работаю в 32х

Comment: JRE не настроен это как ?

Comment: DLL не собран как JNI или используется как JNA до этого пользовался com4j методы определялись.

Comment: пути, явахоум etc, но не в нём дело, видно

Comment: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#my-library-mapping-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror